JSONDecodeError when sending GraphQL query with Scrapy - Possible formatting issue?
I'm working on a Scrapy spider that sends a GraphQL query to an endpoint. I'm encountering a JSONDecodeError when trying to parse the response, which indicates that the response body is empty, I debugged and checked that it is indeed empty. I think that the problem is in the formatting of the query. Here's a summary of the issue and the relevant code:
When sending a GraphQL query using Scrapy, the response results in a JSONDecodeError. The error traceback suggests that the JSON decoder expects a value but finds an empty response instead.
The GraphQL query string:

products_query = '''
            query getProductDetailForProductPage($urlKey: String!) {{
            products(filter: {{ url_key: {{ eq: {urlKey} }} }}) {{
                items {{
                id
                ...ProductDetailsFragment
                ...ClearpayInstallmentsFragment
                ...GoogleTagManagerFragment
                __typename
                }}
                __typename
            }}
            }}

            fragment ProductDetailsFragment on ProductInterface {{
            __typename
            categories {{
                id
                breadcrumbs {{
                category_id
                __typename
                }}
                __typename
            }}
            description {{
                html
                __typename
            }}
            id
            fabric
            href {{
                en_GB
                fr_BE
                nl_BE
                nl_NL
                en_IE
                es_ES
                de_DE
                __typename
            }}
            media_gallery_entries {{
                id
                label
                position
                disabled
                file
                __typename
            }}
            meta_description
            name
            gender_value
            brand_code
            brand
            size_guide
            swatches {{
                product_name
                product_url
                swatch_type
                is_selected
                image_path
                swatch_label
                in_stock
                colour
                __typename
            }}
            colour_attribute_text
            stock_status
            fulfilment {{
                fulfilment_price
                fulfilment_start_date
                fulfilment_end_date
                __typename
            }}
            fulfilment_type
            rrp
            second_id
            price_range {{
                maximum_price {{
                final_price {{
                    currency
                    value
                    __typename
                }}
                __typename
                }}
                __typename
            }}
            sku
            small_image {{
                url
                __typename
            }}
            url_key
            ... on ConfigurableProduct {{
                configurable_options {{
                attribute_code
                attribute_id
                id
                label
                values {{
                    default_label
                    label
                    store_label
                    use_default_value
                    value_index
                    swatch_data {{
                    ... on ImageSwatchData {{
                        thumbnail
                        __typename
                    }}
                    value
                    __typename
                    }}
                    __typename
                }}
                __typename
                }}
                variants {{
                attributes {{
                    code
                    value_index
                    __typename
                }}
                product {{
                    name
                    id
                    sku
                    stock_status
                    rrp
                    fulfilment {{
                    fulfilment_price
                    fulfilment_start_date
                    fulfilment_end_date
                    __typename
                    }}
                    delivery_time_earliest_days
                    delivery_time_latest_days
                    fulfilment_type
                    price_range {{
                    maximum_price {{
                        final_price {{
                        currency
                        value
                        __typename
                        }}
                        __typename
                    }}
                    __typename
                    }}
                    __typename
                }}
                __typename
                }}
                __typename
            }}
            }}
            fragment ClearpayInstallmentsFragment on ProductInterface {{
            clearpayInstallments {{
                installments_logo
                mobile_modal_image
                desktop_modal_image
                __typename
            }}
            __typename
            }}
            fragment GoogleTagManagerFragment on ProductInterface {{
            id
            gtm_product_id
            gtm_category
            dimensions {{
                key
                value
                __typename
            }}
            ... on ConfigurableProduct {{
                variants {{
                product {{
                    id
                    gtm_product_id
                    dimensions {{
                    key
                    value
                    __typename
                    }}
                    gtm_variant
                    __typename
                }}
                __typename
                }}
                __typename
            }}
            __typename
            }}
            '''


This is how I am using it:
for item in items:
    product_url_key = item.get('vg_url_key')

    if not product_url_key:
        self.logger.warning("No product URL key found.")
        return
    
    payload = self.products_query.format(urlKey=product_url_key)
    yield Request(
        url=self.graphql_product_url,
        method='POST',
        headers=self.headers,
        body=json.dumps({'query': payload}),
        callback=self.parse_product,
    )

I think that the problem is in the query. Maybe it is not formatted correctly!? Actually, I am using double {{}} because otherwise it returned me a key error. So, why this query is not fetching data, that is the question, and how to fix it. I think that it is some stupid formatting issue or syntax. So, concentrate on the query string.

You should show the actual exception you are getting, with a traceback.
